# how to restrict anonymous data while using jquery autocomplete plugin

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am using jQuery autocomplete plugin. I want to restrict the user to select the options only available from autocomplete list and he cannot enter the non available. And the data for autocomplete is from the server and not local.

Is there any option to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

you can check user entered value on submit event of form to be valid otherwise ignore form from submitting and show alert ;)